# Using custom-defined IP address vs DHCP on Different Networks

Tags: macos, networking, mac, wireless-networking, dhcp

On Mac OSX, is it possible to let the computer obtain a specific IP address (192.168.1.123) on wireless network #1, and let DHCP assign it a dynamic IP address on all other wireless entworks?

Answer (score 0):

1) On-board-solution [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28842/how-to-configure-a-static-ip-for-a-specific-access-point-on-os-x):

Use *System/Network/Location/Edit Location* and configure two different Networks (i.e. Home & Elswhere). There you can configure different settings.

---

2) To automate switching between Locations you could try [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/341182/mac-network-locations-automatic-selection-by-available-network):

Use a tool like [Locomatic](http://www.45rpmsoftware.com/locamatic.php) to automate the process of switching Location settings by network.